# Node JS Not getting error returns from exported promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

Not sure if my syntax is correct. I have a promise that I export:

```
module.exports = {
   getResults:(request_id)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      pool.query(resultsSql,request_id, (error, results, fields)=>{
        if (error){
          reject(error);
        }
        resolve(results);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

sql statment is a variable defined in a previous step. I am importing the file into my main function and calling it with something like this.

```
reqdb.getResults(request_id).then((result)=>{
   //do something with result
}).catch((error)=>{
  //return error
});
```

I tried various things even a try catch block in my exported promise. I see the error inside the promise code but when I use a reject block the error is empty in the calling function. I have tried reject(error) and throw new error(error)

Comment: Is `resultsSql` undefined? What sql are you using? your promise syntax looks correct. I would suspect you want to make your getResults function accept a sql statement. Maybe I read the question wrong, are you getting results successfully but just not catching errors?

Comment: It was the reject in the getResults function. It didn't activate the .catch in the calling function.